# Check existing email with jquery validate

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have these codes for checking existing mail before registration but I cant get it work. Where is the error in code? I really can't see it.

This is my jquery validate code:

```
<script>
    $("#form").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: '#errors',
        rules:{
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: "checkmail.php"
            },
            pasw: {
                equalTo: "#pas",
                minlength: 6
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

And this is checkmail.php:

```
<?php
    require("db.php");

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $query = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 0){
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
?>
```

Input is normal `<input class="span4" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" required>`

UPDATE:
Console says this for url (it's ok):

```
http://web/checkmail.php?email=mail%40mail.com
```

And this is response:

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE email='' LIMIT 1true
```

so mail is missing in select

Comment: if script is loading before form need to wrap code in a `ready` handler. Otherwise need more details from your console. Is request being made and returning expected results?

Comment: ahh  it's a GET request and you are looking for a Post

Comment: @charlietfl hmmm, for some resaon console returns fine result with GET and without mysqli_real_escape_string but then jquery validate doesnt show up. every mail passes

Comment: its working now. setting header fixed it: `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0):

I think is validate is using get method for ajax. So in place of $_POST you need to use $_GET or you can try $_REQUEST as it work for both get and post

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']);
```